# help with focusing a dynamically created input

Tags: jquery

my code is this. on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KH7pZ/1/).

```
var inp = $('<input>').attr({'class':'txtEdit txt', 
    'type':'text'})
    .val($(this).html()).blur(function (){
        if($(this).val().length != ''){
            $(txt).replaceWith($(editable)
                .html($(this).val()));
        }
        else{ alert("Cannot contain empty value!")}
    }).keydown(function (e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 9){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).trigger('blur');
            }
    }).appendTo($(txt));
```

I am creating an input element with lots of events and adding to div. Now i want to focus it as it is appended to DOM. but focus does not seem to be working.

Here's the total code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My jQuery plugin</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function ()
            {
                    $('.editable').txtEdit();
            });

            (function($){
                $.fn.txtEdit = function() {
                    var editable = $(this);

                    $(editable).live('click', 
                        function ()
                        {
                            var txt = $('<div>').attr('class', 'txtEdit div');
                            var inp = $('<input>').attr({'class':'txtEdit txt', 
                                            'type':'text'})
                                        .val($(this).html()).blur(function (){
                                                if($(this).val().length != ''){
                                                    $(txt).replaceWith($(editable)
                                                        .html($(this).val()));
                                                }
                                                else{ alert("Cannot contain empty value!")}
                                            }).keydown(function (e){
                                                    if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 9){
                                                        e.preventDefault();
                                                        $(this).trigger('blur');
                                                    }
                                            }).appendTo($(txt));
                            $(this).replaceWith(txt);                           
                        }
                    );
                };
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="editable">this is editable div</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone any ideas??

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add

```
inp.focus();
```

after

```
$(this).replaceWith(txt);
```

Because your div is created after focus action, which is wrong.
You should display the div and then focus on input.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of chaining the focus add this after creating the input box.

```
inp.focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
inp.focus();
```

after the `$(this).replaceWith(txt);`

What you were doing is trying to focus the element before you add it to the DOM (*while it was still in memory*).

live at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/KH7pZ/8/

Answer (score 1):

You need to put

```
inp.focus();
```

At the end of your code (once the replacement is done);

Here's your updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KH7pZ/9/